# Python difflib.Differ with Contextual difference

Tags: python, difflib

How can I get contextual difference (e.i only the lines with difference and not all lines) along with comparing the characters within a Line using difflib.Differ()

Example

```
>>> text1 = '''  1. 111
...   2. 222
...   3. 333
...   4. 444
... '''.splitlines(1)
>>> text2 = '''  1. 121 xxx
...   2. 222
...   3. 313
...   4. 444
... '''.splitlines(1)
>>> from difflib import Differ
>>> d = Differ()
>>> 
>>> print ''.join(d.compare(text1, text2))
-   1. 111
+   1. 121 xxx
    2. 222
-   3. 333
?       ^
+   3. 313
?       ^
    4. 444

>>> 


# I want something like this with context=True
>>> print ''.join(d.compare(text1, text2))
-   1. 111
+   1. 121 xxx
-   3. 333
?       ^
+   3. 313
?       ^
```

**UPDATE:**
I have answered it here: [python difflib character diff with unifed contextual format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719633/python-difflib-character-diff-with-unifed-contextual-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you can filter the results, removing lines that start with whitespace. A list comprehension and str.startswith can do that.

```
>>> from difflib import Differ
>>> d = Differ()
>>> print ''.join(line for line in d.compare(text1, text2) if not line.startswith(' '))
-   1. 111
+   1. 121 xxx
-   3. 333
?       ^
+   3. 313
?       ^
```